# Best strategy for hiding an object in a scene

Tags: rendering, objects, edit-mode

Please excuse my newbie questions. I have a scene that has chairs. I don't want to delete them (in case I need them later), I just want to make them not visible at render, so I can composite a chair shot in green screen with an actor into the scene. (keeping them in edit also helps me know where my chairs will be). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use layers (on the bottom horizontal bar of your 3D View): Select your objet and press <kbd>M</kbd> to put it on the layer of your choice. Click on the layer if you want to make it visible, and <kbd>shift</kbd> click to make several layers visible.

[image]

Comment: Man! That was simply a great answer to my question, and I learned about layers in the process. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest** way is to select an object and click, in the Outliner, the eye icon next to it. Clicking again makes it visible. The camera icon, one of the remaining two, excludes the object from rendering.

Comment: This will only hide the object in the viewport, not during render.

Comment: There are THREE icons in the Outliner. Click the camera one if you don't want the object  to be rendered.